# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for using El Capitan Split View for Mac?

Tags: macos

**This question is about Mac El Capitan SplitView**

I am a fan of using splitscreen views as in [i3](https://i3wm.org/) for linux.

Or when I am on Windows I use [snapping](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/snap-a-truly-slick-feature-in-windows-10/)

With the new feature is there a way to use it without touching the mouse?

So far I've only seen that you can use it by setting it to fullscreen-mode and then use Mission Control for it. [new-split-screen](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-os-x-el-capitans-new-split-screen-mode)

Comment: @MarekH there is now answer in that thread!!

Comment: Cmd +` (that's a backtick) for swaping the focus. I deleted the answer because they wanted to swap views not to swap focus from one window to antoher. Another part of answer was Amethyst https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst

Comment: What does "use it mean"? Do you mean is there a way to split-screen a window and pick the other window to place beside it without using the mouse? Just the keyboard?

Answer (score 16):

No shortcuts for Split Screen in El Capitan as far as I am aware.

However ShiftIt (completely free!) is amazing for this! Like just unbelievably brilliant.

Been using it since Mountain Lion.

https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt/releases

Can also be installed via [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew cask install ShiftIt
```

FYI I am in no way associated with this software's development.

Comment: Massive plus 1 for ShiftIt. Wonderful tool.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that Spectacle is the way to go!

[spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that there aren't keyboard shortcuts for native split screen mode.

However, I use a cheaper program called **[BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)** (as of 07/27/2016 is $2.99 USD in the App Store) and it does have keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/). It's free and serve my need. You can split screen in any direction. You can also configure its shortcuts to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are no keyboard shortcuts to activate this feature of OS X currently. The primary way to activate it is to click and hold down the Green traffic light and select another available window to use in split screen.

Comment: Note that this _isn't_ the "only" way. You can also use Ctrl+Cmd+F to make an app _independently_ fullscreen and then drag another window onto it in Mission Control.

Comment: "without touching the mouse"

Comment: It's so annoying that OSX doesn't support the power users anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily with [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) ($36).

Create two macros, with whatever keyboard shortcuts you like, one for focussing the lefthand pane, and another to focus the right one.

Use the **Move and Click** action to **Click** the **Left Button** relative to **the Absolute Postion**.

You need to set the x, y coordinates according to the size of your display. The height isn't too important (I just used the halfway point), but you'll want KM to click near to the sides of the display, so the clicks will always be in the correct pane, even if you resize them.

---

Obviously, $36 is a lot to fix one thing, but KM can do a lot of useful stuff, so you will probably find it's worth it, especially if you like doing everything with shortcuts.